# Duplicate column name - inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query :

```
SELECT FinancialMoein.*,
       FinancialMoein.kol_code as kol_code ,
       TBFC.kol_code as parent_code 
FROM (
       SELECT TP.*,
              ifnull(TP.kol_code,TP.moein_code) as code,
              ifnull(TR.title, TP.title_en) AS title,
              ifnull(TR.description, TP.description_en) AS description
       FROM Tb_Financial_Coddings TP LEFT JOIN 
             (
               SELECT title,
                      description,
                      financial_codding_id 
               FROM Tb_Financial_Coddings_Translations 
               WHERE locale = @Locale
             ) TR  
       ON TR.financial_codding_id = TP.id
       WHERE TP.type = 'kol' AND TP.deleted_at IS NULL
     ) as FinancialMoein INNER JOIN Tb_Financial_Coddings TBFC 
ON FinancialMoein.parent_id = TBFC.id;
```

but I got this error message:

> Duplicate column name 'kol_code'

Comment: I suppose `FinancialMoein.*` returns the same column

Comment: `FinancialMoein.*` will select all columns. Then `FinancialMoein.kol_code` will select that column specifically. So effectively you are selecting the same column twice. And `as kol_code` is a pointless alias because you aren't actually changing the name of the column. Therefore you've selected the same column twice, with the same name. It's not logical, it's not useful, and it's not allowed either. Either a) don't use *, and just select exactly the columns you want, or b) remove the redundant explicit selection of `FinancialMoein.kol_code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FinancialMoein.*` in select clause already includes the column `kol_code` since it is derived using table `Tb_Financial_Coddings` which has the column `kol_code`. Then again you are selecting it with the same name, hence there is issue. You have to keep the different names for all the columns. You may try below query to ignore the issue -

```
SELECT FinancialMoein.*,
       FinancialMoein.kol_code as kol_code_2,
       TBFC.kol_code as parent_code 
FROM (
       SELECT TP.*,
              ifnull(TP.kol_code,TP.moein_code) as code,
              ifnull(TR.title, TP.title_en) AS title,
              ifnull(TR.description, TP.description_en) AS description
       FROM Tb_Financial_Coddings TP LEFT JOIN 
             (
               SELECT title,
                      description,
                      financial_codding_id 
               FROM Tb_Financial_Coddings_Translations 
               WHERE locale = @Locale
             ) TR  
       ON TR.financial_codding_id = TP.id
       WHERE TP.type = 'kol' AND TP.deleted_at IS NULL
     ) as FinancialMoein INNER JOIN Tb_Financial_Coddings TBFC 
ON FinancialMoein.parent_id = TBFC.id;
```

Rather you may just remove the column `FinancialMoein.kol_code as kol_code,` from the outer select to ignore the error.